# El orden de las etiquetas es importante?

Tags: html

Me gustaría saber si el orden de las etiquetas es relevante para no que dé error un código. Por ejemplo poner:

```
<b><font size="8">Palabra</font size></b>
```

O sería más adecuado poner las negritas dentro?

Gracias :)

Comment: El tag [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) se cierra con `</font>` y su uso no esta recomendado. Al margen de eso, en el caso que planteas ambos elementos son de [presentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display) en linea (_no de bloque_) y ninguno pisa estilos del anterior,  por lo que el orden para dicho caso no es relevante. En el caso que algunas de las razones anteriores si se cumpliera, te diría que el orden si es relevante.

Answer (score -1):

**No debes usar la etiqueta `font` en HTML** ya que no está soportada por HTML5 **([deprecada](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp))**.

El uso de **la etiqueta `b` [tampoco se recomienda](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp)**, se deben usar encabezados en su lugar (h1, h2, ...) para títulos o la etiqueta `strong` para resaltar un contenido en el texto (a nivel semántico).

###### Recomendaciones

- Consultar las guías de referencia de elementos HTML como:
  [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element) o https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element
- Usar una [herramienta para validar el HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) revelará errores al anidar elementos HTML y otros posibles problemas.

###### Referencias

- [Etiqueta HTML font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)
- [Notas sobre la etiqueta HTML b](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b#notas)

Comment: Esto.. ni es una respuesta.. es mas una recomendacion...

Answer (score -2):

El orden es bueno de obedecer, por semántica. Primero es el TAG padre, que dice que es cada cosa, en tu caso `font`, una etiqueta de HTML4 no de HTML5 que es el actual, que se usaba para especificar texto con propiedades como tamaño y otros.

Bien, dentro de `font` debería ir el tag de **negrita** `<b>`, esto para un mejor orden y mejor semántica, peeeeero...

Lo ideal seria hacerlo con CSS

```css
span{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.word{
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<b><font size="8">Palabra</font></b>
<br>
<span>Palabra</span>
<br>
<span class="word">Palabra</span>
```

Y ya no usar la etiqueta `<b>` de HTML. Por lo general yo trabajo con la tercera forma...

Comment: Osea @gbianchi que debo tener tu permiso / perspectiva / o punto de vista para responder???? Lo que amerite una respuesta lo decide cada quien. En lugar de estar haciendo ver mal lo que los demás hacen, deberías hacer algo tu...

Comment: Bueno.. vamos de vuelta.. bueno de obedecer =! que importante. igual, no estas contestando la pregunta. la respuesta es ese comentario que le dejaron.

Comment: Pero si respondo, es lo primero que hago, le digo que el orden es importante por semántica, esa es mi respuesta, que otro no crea que es importante es su respuesta/perspectiva. A mi ver si debe seguir el orden que yo le respondo y a parte de eso le aconsejo lo que debe hacer. En la mayoría de preguntas de SOes hacemos eso, respondemos pero luego hacemos nuestra propia valoración, no veo que hagas esto con las respuestas de A.Cedano por ejemplo, y el es un excelente ejemplo de encaminar a los usuarios a las buenas practicas. Como quieres que el sitio "tenga movimiento" si haces cosas como esta?

Comment: no voy a discutir contigo.. hasta aqui llego. ya te di mi punto de vista.. si quiees lo hablamos en otro ambito..

Comment: Pero dar su punto de vista es válido, lo que no es válido es decir que mi respuesta **NO ES UNA RESPUESTA** solo porque a usted no le guste o no le ayude en nada. Yo creo que al OP, que es al que le importa esta pregunta, si le puede ayudar y mucho mi respuesta. Y no, no necesito discutir más, pero vamos que con unos usted es bien cerrado, y con otros es super permisible, se la valgo si fuera un usuario normal, pero usted es un moderador, tiene poder sobre muchas cosas más que yo, y se ve feo que usted quiera definir que es una respuesta válida o no basado en su gusto. Fin del tema...

Comment: Mira.. soy igual de duro con todos.. hasta con los otros moderadores... basicamente, la pregunta dice, importa el orden? y tu respuesta dice el orden es bueno de obedecer... pero.. importa??? que sea bueno, no quiere decir que importe... o sea, no responde la pregunta... la respuesta, no es incorrecta, si no que no responde la pregunta, que pregunta si importa o no.